# Dylib error 'Library not loaded' distributing application

Tags: opencv, vtk, objective-c++, dyld

I'm developing an app in objective-C++ that uses dynamic libraries of OpenCV and VTK but I've a problem on distribution, if I launch my app in a different system I got this issue:

Dyld Error Message:

```
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libvtkCommon.5.6.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libvtkCommon.5.6.1.dylib: open() failed with errno=13
    /myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libvtkCommon.5.6.1.dylib: open() failed with errno=13
```

I've rebuilt my dylibs with install_name_tool to point to: `@executable_path/../Frameworks` and in "build phase" of myApp's target I've added "copy files" phase with destination "Frameworks" for my dylibs. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your application bundle and make sure the file that got copied into Frameworks is the actual dylib and not a symbolic link file. Also, did you run install_name_tool on both the dylib file and your executable? Look [at this page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq09-mac-deployment.html) under **Shared Libraries** for an example.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856029/deploy-and-distribute-opencv-applications-with-xcode4-on-mac-osx).